# Read and Write to SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have the script that will write info to the database, but how can I have it print the variable "time" from the database after it updated the same query based on the email entered to write to database? This is for use with JSON.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';


$dbuser = 'casaange_testapp';
$dbpass = 'testapp1';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('casaange_volunteertest');
$email= $_POST['email'];
$time= $_POST['time'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET time= '$time' WHERE email = '$email'";



$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}

if($retval){
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Update successful!";
die(json_encode($response));
}

//echo '{"success":1, "message":"Time added!"}';
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="timeinsert.php">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Email:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Time:</td>
<td><input name="time" type="text" id="time"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to know is whether the UPDATE query actually changed the value in the database?

You can use `mysql_affected_rows()` see how many rows changed as a result of your query - in your case it will be either 1 or 0.

If you need to return the time that you just put into the database, you can query the value that actually went into the database by selecting it back out with the email address as the key.

A few general observations about your code, if I may:

- You *must* escape that POST data before putting it into an SQL query
  like that. At best it'll be a source of bugs, worst a massive
  security hole.
- If you're writing new code, as you appear to be here, you should
  consider using the newer MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions instead of
  the old MySQL calls.
- You can use `json_encode` to turn an associative PHP array into a JSON
  object, instead of building a JSON string yourself.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to return the time variable that was just updated in the database? I am new to PHP, so I don't know all these commands yet.